# Can a minecraft plugin control the player?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm new to java but have a lot of experience with C#. I'm thinking of creating a client side minecraft plugin that will turn the player exactly 90 degrees when a key is pressed. I've only ever seen this done with custom clients like darkbot and never actual plugins. Before I start I'd like to check that this is actually possible? (and relatively simple)

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: Is it possible?  Probably.  But that's really a question that's entirely too broad for here...

Comment: Why the downvote? If a question about programming with a yes/no (and maybe a reference) answer is too broad for here then where would you recommend I ask? If you don't know about a subject then don't comment on it.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But questions like these are often thinly-veiled "give me the code" questions, which are too broad. Asking for recommendations of tutorial, references, APIs, or other third-party resources are also off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to use bukkit, you could try [this](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/icontrolu/). I don't think it would be hard to recreate using the sponge API; all it does is teleport the controlled player to the controlling player whenever the latter's position updates.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is very possible. Look here:

http://www.curse.com/bukkit-plugins/minecraft/icontrolu

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the old Bukkit API, it could. However, bukkit is now DCMA'd. I would assume that it is possible with [Sponge](http://www.spongepowered.org/). You can use it to control a player, however..

I know that you can move a player to a set coordinates, or make them look a particular direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think he is talking about a mod. Not a plugin. Anyway, to do this using forge you just will need to set the player's coords to his, but different head rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can download the plugin:
http://www.curse.com/bukkit-plugins/minecraft/icontrolu

Ohterwise to control players by sudoing cmds you need to install EssentialsX.
Note: The 'X' in EssentialsX is necessary. Older Versions don't work anymore and will not supported

regards

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible with coordinates, you can change the face of players, and the position they are standing at, so you can add that to a minecraft plugin